# What is the following command "typedef mpc_val_t*(*mpc_apply_t)(mpc_val_t*);"

Tags: c++, c

Can someone provide an explanation of the following command?

```
typedef mpc_val_t*(*mpc_apply_t)(mpc_val_t*);
```

Comment: `mpc_apply_t` is declared as a name for the type "pointer to function taking `mpc_val_t*` and returning `mpc_val_t*`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type definition for `mpc_apply_t`, defining it as a pointer to a function accepting a pointer to a value of type `mpc_val_t`, and returning a pointer to a value of type `mpc_val_t`. The type `mpc_val_t` is defined elsewhere.